# What does revert do in Azure Release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

On a release pipeline's history tab, you can select the ellipses on each record and choose to compare the difference or revert pipeline.

What does the revert option do? Does it revert the selected version (change) out of the latest pipeline? or does it revert the latest pipeline to the selected version (just after the change was made)?

Comment: Agree with Shayki's sample, the revert here means revert the latest pipeline to the selected version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The revert tell Azure Pipelines to make the definition like the version you click "Revert Pipeline".

For example - I have 4 versions of my pipeline:

1) An empty pipeline.

2) One stage.

3) One Stage + Second Stage.

4) One Stage + Second Stage + This stage.

Now I have 3 stages in my release pipeline.

If I want to go back and delete my last 2 stages I need to go the History tab, to the second line that represents the creation of `2) One stage` and click there on "Revert Pipeline". the pipeline will be with One stage only, like the version I clicked to revert.

Comment: So it is "revert to". Instead of just "revert". They should have been more clear isnt it?

Comment: Yes, I agree :)